# no build set file found 4.11/rtems-sparc on rtems (VB)

Tags: installation, virtualbox, sparc, rtems

```
. ~/rtems-4.11-work/setenv 
cd /home/rtems/rtems-source-builder/rtems
../source-builder/sb-set-builder \
--log=1-sparc.txt \
--prefix=${HOME}/rtems-4.11-work/tools 4.11/rtems-sparc
```

I did all steps well.Lastly I am trying to install sparc tools ,but when I try to do this commend line, it return to me

```
"Rtems Source Builder - Set Builder, 5 (35c533f545c8)
Build set: 4.11/rtems-sparc
error: no build set file found: 4.11/rtems-sparc.bset
Build FAILED"
```

I am vorking RTEMS on VirtualBox
Does anyone help me? Because this will be my graduation Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note multiple possible reasons:

- There is a `=` sign in your first line. Shouldn't it be `. ~/rtems-4.11-work/setenv`?
- I'm not sure which guide you are using for reference. But if you checked out the head of the rtems-source-builder git repository, your version is incorrect. RTEMS is already at version 5. For 4.11 you have to use the 4.11 branch.

To get some more details, you could try the following command:

```
../source-builder/sb-set-builder --list-bsets
```

This will give you a list of valid build sets.

If you are trying to build for an existing project, please ask your colleagues for the exact version of RTEMS you should use. Otherwise I would recommend to use the development HEAD which is version 5.

**Edit:**

With the new information that you gave in your comments I'll try to make that answer a little more useful:

If you really want to use that old VM: It should be enough to replace your last command by the following:

```
../source-builder/sb-set-builder \
    --log=1-sparc.txt \
    --prefix=${HOME}/rtems-4.11-work/tools 5/rtems-sparc
```

Note that this will give you a RTEMS 5 while a lot of the paths still have an 4.11 in it.

My recommended way would be to set up some up to date Linux in an VM (for example an CentOS 7 with development packets) and follow the guides in some of the last years GSoC blogs. I think most of the students wrote something about their first steps.

Basically it should be about the following steps. Note that this is normally my approach. You can also use RSB to build the BSP directly. I do it in an extra step in the following. Please also note that I wrote these down from my head. So I might miss some step or have some typo in it.

- create your working directory

  ```
  mkdir -p $HOME/rtems-install/rtems/5/bin
  ```
- Clone current RTEMS and source builder:

  ```
  cd $HOME
  git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems.git
  git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git
  ```
- Set PATH so it contains your rtems devel environment. I would recommend to do that in some environment file or the bashrc. But you can also do it every time you start a console:

  ```
  export PATH="$HOME/rtems-install/rtems/5/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- Build your tools (this needs a lot of time; multiple hours on a single core machine; if you give multiple cores to your VM it will speed up a lot)

  ```
  cd $HOME/rtems-source-builder/rtems
  ../source-builder/sb-set-builder \
      --log="rsb-sparc.log" \
      --prefix="$HOME/rtems-install/rtems/5/" \
      --without-rtems \
      "5/rtems-sparc"
  ```
- Build and install RTEMS BSP (erc32 for the sparc simulator in this example):

  ```
  cd $HOME/rtems
  ./bootstrap
  mkdir $HOME/rtems-build
  cd $HOME/rtems-build
  "${HOME}/rtems/configure" \
      "--target=sparc" \
      "--prefix=$HOME/rtems-install/rtems/5/" \
      "--enable-rtemsbsp=erc32" \
      "--enable-tests=samples" \
      "--disable-networking"
  make
  make install
  ```
- You now should have a BSP installed in $HOME/rtems-install/rtems/5/.

For the BBB I also created a repo some time back that contains scripts to do all the necessary steps. See https://gitlab.com/c-mauderer/rtems-bbb.

Comment: I follewed this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDouBRcWdm0  . I have rtems-4.11-work folder in my RTEMS folder but when I check  "../source-builder/sb-set-builder --list-bsets"  this list all bset files version 5

Comment: The video is showing a long gone version of the RTEMS wiki. The Sourceforge project for the VM images are still existent. So I assume you used one of the images? Most likely the 20121128. Please note that these are horribly old too.

_edit: Sent too early. Here is the rest:_

There is a git pull step in the video. So you updated to the latest head. In that case you won't have any 4.11 any more but only version 5.

I would recommend to use an up to date Linux VM and the current GSoC Getting Started page for a starting point: https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/GSoC/GettingStarted

Comment: Thank you I have read all instruction but I still couldt find or didn't get how to reinstall or how to build RTEMS. In this case I got my problem it is about version as you said. But I dont know what I need to change on my code. I am very new on RTEMS. If you can help me I will be greadful

Comment: Would you be able to give some more details what you want to do? Do you need  exactly that tutorial (because someone pointed you toward it)? Do you target a special platform (the Sparc simulator from the tutorial, a beagle bone black, some custom hardware, ...) or do you just need any simulator? Do you try to change an existing application or do you want to start with debugging through a hello world application? You used a Virtual Machine. What is your normal host platform? If it is any flavor of Linux or Unix it might would be simpler to use it directly.

Comment: PS: Maybe it would be a good idea to add these information to your original question.

Comment: In fact I will work on BBB and I ordered it. But untill it came I am trying to do some exercises on VirtualBox. But when I try to ınstall sparc it gave me that error(which we think it about version). I followed all instraction but I didnt get what I need to change on my commentline.

Comment: I extended my original answer with some more details.